# opening a window on second monitor (screen) with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, multiple-monitors

I want to open a window popup on second monitor automatically. I try to open it with javascript but the popup recline to my first screen's right top. When I use mouse it can fit on second screen but I dont want to use mouse, I want to do it automatically
my javascript code:

```
window.open("Pop.aspx", "Pop.aspx", "width=10,height=10,screenX=1800,screenY=0");
```

I change screenX property many times but it didn't work.

Any Idea?

Comment: Nope, not possible. No way to specify which screen the new window will show. It's also not fully possible to specify whether the window opens as a window or a tab in the browser either

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a new browser page on the second monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293777/opening-a-new-browser-page-on-the-second-monitor)