# Opening a browser window on a projector

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to develop a presentation system that will include interactive functionality as part of the presentation. What I'd like to do is have a screen that the audience can access via their browser, on this screen the current slide will be displayed along with a chat/comments section (haven't really decided which) and a section for footnotes with links that can be followed to other relevant information.

The problem I'm having at the moment is that for the presenter view, I can not seem to get JavaScript to open a window on the projector at all. The best I can do is open a window, drag it over to the projector screen, and make it full-screen, but I would rather have that automated.

Currently I am using NodeJS/HTML5, but I'm open to any solutions, including the use of Flash/Java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control which monitor a browser window opens onn aside from specifying size and position.

See [Opening a new browser page on the second monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293777/opening-a-new-browser-page-on-the-second-monitor) and [How do I get JavaScript to open a popup window on the current monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652/how-do-i-get-javascript-to-open-a-popup-window-on-the-current-monitor).

Comment: I have not been able to open a window or move an already opened window off of the primary screen using JavaScript (tested in Chrome 31, Firefox 26, and IE 11). I have my second monitor set to the right of my primary monitor. What happens when I try to move the window past the boundary of the primary screen, is that the boundary of the window moves to the boundary of the primary screen and stops.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, that is why I'm asking for alternative solutions perhaps using Flash/Java, or some sort of screencast to keep the audience's view synced with the presentation.